# HTML5 Video element does not a resume live streaming when a stream is interrupted then restarts

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, live-streaming

I'm using JW Player to live stream content onto a web page. The player is backed by an open-source library called [cine.io](http://www.cine.io).

My issue is that the player falls back to an HTML 5 video element for all mobile web, both on iPhone and Android. There are some differences between the flash solution of JW Player and HTML5 - notably that if a live stream starts, then stops, then restarts, **the video element will not pick up the restarted stream.**

This is a problem since streams often drop in and out - and the flash solution does pick up the restarted stream.

I tested a bunch of listener methods on the video and the only one that signalled that the stream had ended was a "time update" listener:

```
     $video.on('timeupdate', function(){
//Do something        
               });
```

However none of my attempts to re-open the stream have been effective.

Is this even possible? Can anyone provide pointers?

Comment: My experience has shown that the video support under Android is extremely buggy (even on the newest devices). Your best bet is to create a native app and use ExoPlayer that offers better error recovery. The situation under iOS is better but, again, no error recovery. If you want it you'll have to do it natively. There are also commercial solutions that claim to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Would an example like this work?

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1442607-example-a-custom-error-message

Comment: I think those commands are for the JW Flash player - the methods described in hte help section don't apply when the player falls back to HTML 5 - unless you have a different experience?

Comment: Those API commands work for both rendering modes. Should work in HTML5 as well.

Comment: I think the API I'm using, called cine.io, is actually falling back on a html5 video player that is not a JWPlayer wrapper. Check out their code here: https://github.com/cine-io/broadcast-js-sdk/blob/master/src/play_stream.coffee

Comment: If it is falling back to a static html5 <video> tag, then our API methods won't get called, since our player won't be used. However, we have a HTML5 player as well, which you could use instead of the video tag fallback, and then our API methods would work.

Comment: OK that's what I thought. The API I'm using falls backon a static HTM5 <video> tag. We're working on an MVP so I'm not going to rebuild for now but in the near future I'll look at this.

Comment: Okay, sounds like a plan!